# Variable in looping only stores the first process data

Tags: r, loops

I want to save the results of the process in looping but it turns out that the data stored is only the first data processed.

```
k=1
l=1

E <- c()
sigma_es <- c() 

while (k <= 170) {
  Es <- c()
    while(l <= 720){
      E <- (obs[[1]][l]-tab[[1]][2*k-1]-(tab[[1]][2*k]*era5[l,k]))^2
      Es <- c(Es,E)
      hold <- sum(Es)
      print(paste("l= ",l,"dan k= ",k," akumulasi error=",hold))
      l=l+1
    }
  sigma_es <- c(sigma_es,hold)
  k=k+1
}
```

I've tried to use data frames and matrix but the results still can't save all the results. pls, help me to solve it

here the sample data i use:

obs data

```
structure(list(Temp = c(20.6, 23.2, 25, 27.4, 28.8, 29.2, 30, 
29.4, 29.4, 29.2, 28, 26.6, 26.2, 20, 22.4, 25.2, 27, 29, 29.6, 
29.4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

tab data

```
structure(list(Estimate = c(21.8622017063543, 0.149905976990255, 
21.8792372021679, 0.149106548969244, 22.483179270103, 0.125959278859866, 
23.0223290054929, 0.105312788847492, 22.7764521125954, 0.114936945277311
), `Std. Error` = c(2.37994644400538, 0.0916220989468571, 2.63859044098663, 
0.101496001085481, 2.67417945176719, 0.102946780235079, 2.71999289764186, 
0.104833205410304, 2.8011149786195, 0.108097071239478), `t value` = c(9.1860057445498, 
1.63613340791509, 8.29201715518484, 1.46908791848523, 8.40750580715343, 
1.22353781800886, 8.46411364730125, 1.00457472835359, 8.13120928146282, 
1.06327529469027), `Pr(>|t|)` = c(4.30028996897647e-19, 0.102249907076108, 
5.47881708292241e-16, 0.142246934658274, 2.2472335679596e-16, 
0.221528011106171, 1.44672121858366e-16, 0.315440097658094, 1.86410772248374e-15, 
0.288014595967456)), row.names = c("(Intercept)", "2 _uji", "(Intercept)1", 
"3 _uji", "(Intercept)2", "4 _uji", "(Intercept)3", "5 _uji", 
"(Intercept)4", "6 _uji"), class = "data.frame")
```

era5 data

```
structure(c(25.5656043, 25.69174497, 26.19046783, 26.95023182, 
27.60604654, 28.1500282, 28.39544774, 28.46275197, 28.1386405, 
28.0857899, 26.1006802, 26.24988827, 26.53224483, 26.87635776, 
27.19273143, 27.47435801, 27.64108561, 27.74561886, 27.75525461, 
27.81204711, 26.58786936, 26.68043093, 26.81343342, 26.98147499, 
27.12002534, 27.27697121, 27.40281989, 27.51976281, 27.66225506, 
27.76474436), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), NULL))
```

and here i got the output:

```
    c(4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 
4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493, 
4385.62165935493, 4385.62165935493)
```

but i want to get the output like this:

```
c(4385.621659, 4388.780521, 4392.813546
)
```

Comment: my bad, thank you for reminding me

Comment: can you explain what is 170 and 720 in your `while` loop and what you are trying to calculate with `E <- (obs[[1]][l]-tab[[1]][2*k-1]-(tab[[1]][2*k]*era5[l,k]))^2` ?

Comment: 170 is colomn and 720 is row in data
E <- (obs[[1]][l]-tab[[1]][2*k-1]-(tab[[1]][2*k]*era5[l,k]))^2 is how i calculate the error each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after 1st iteration of `while` loop is done you need to initialize `l` again because it is still at the last calculated value and doesn't go inside the `while` loop.

```
k=1
E <- c()
sigma_es <- c() 

while (k <= 170) {
   Es <- c()
   l = 1 #<- Initializing here
   while(l <= 720){
      E <- (obs[[1]][l]-tab[[1]][2*k-1]-(tab[[1]][2*k]*era5[l,k]))^2
      Es <- c(Es,E)
      hold <- sum(Es)
      print(paste("l= ",l,"dan k= ",k," akumulasi error=",hold))
      l=l+1
   }
  sigma_es <- c(sigma_es,hold)
  k=k+1
}
```